# How can i redirect a web server to a specific url?

Tags: web-services, http, labview

**Hi guys.** 
   I create a public content under my web service. I am trying to replace index.html to public content. Then i will be able to send data to that web page in labview. Any helpful idea?

[here is the project part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lATb7.png)

[here is the vi part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsNmX.png)

Comment: How do you send data to website with client? :) You need http server don't you?

Comment: I am not sure but post.vi works? or not? :) Please give more information :)

Comment: You should consider reading this: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/   ___ Than this: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7747/en/.   I think all your questions will be answered here. Also I would suggest reading about server-client connections in general

Comment: Finally I would suggest removing your question as it is very general and kind a "Please help" me

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) but i dont think that the question is very general actually i think it is too specific :)

Comment: You are asking how to send data using HTTP client, but you did not research and do NOT know that website itself is a client and another client can NOT send data to another client. There should be a server. That server in LabVIEW implemented using LV web services (I sent the link). So you should dive in. You are asking about how to send data to website from LabVIEW using HTTP. I can edit your question and answer, receiving points. BUT I won't going to do so, because your question is simply "Do this instead of me". The specific question would be like "I bump this error when sending http data".

Comment: I didnt want you or anyone to create a new vi. I showed my vi and asked what is wrong with it. And i wont discuss with you about my question's generality. If you dont want then dont answer...

Comment: Man, I am asking you to read about LabVIEW web services. You are using HTTP Client API, which is intended to send HTTP requests to servers, NOT to websites (they are clients). To be able to send HTTP requests to a website you should be using LabVIEW web services. The answer to your question is "Everything is wrong with it". But this is very general and I am not able to post this as an answer. SO has rules and they want a specific question and specific answer. Please go ahead try with LV web services and post another question if they will arise.

Comment: I updated my vi. Am i on the right way? And how can i redirect my webservice to a specific url? I took the index.html of the web page that i want to go and i placed it under the public content but it failed.

Comment: It seems yes, now you can update your question and ask a specific question and I think people here will be able to help. Thanks

Comment: can you take a look the picture that called project part? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Well. The project should look like this. 
[image]

So, please consider placing the index.html directly under Public Content folder.

Then right click on your VI and select the appropriate method. 
Then right click and select "Show Method URL".

If you want a VI that receives some value from index.html and then replies with other values you can specify inputs and outputs (you should connect them to connector pane).

- To be able to use all features of HTTP you might want to right click on web service under project hierarchy select properties, go to HTTP Method VI Settings, select your VI, Go to Output Type and change to Stream.
  [image]
  If you change this to Stream, then you can use "Write Response.vi", output terminals will not work.

After all this you right click on web service and select start, then right click Application web server and select Publish.

Please use these links as references: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7747/en/

http://www.bloomy.com/sites/bloomy.com/files/bloomy_whitepaper_upandrunningwithlabviewwebservices.pdf

You can email me if you want me to send you examples, but there are lot of examples online. 
My email is: khachiksah.91@gmail.com

Comment: thank you very much. If result again fail, when i clarify all code, i will ask your help again. have a good day

Comment: I sent you a mail that include my all project in a zip file. I hope you take a look it. (mail address => cagricam01@gmail.com)